# Make a list of matrices where each matrix is one row of dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, error-handling, apply, do.call

I would like to make a list of 2x2 matrices, where each row of a dataframe becomes a 2x2 matrix. I will be working with a huge dataset (toy example for convenience) so I am trying to figure out how to do this without for loops. I have been trying to do this using a homemade function and apply() but I get an error message.

```
dat<-data.frame(x1=c(2,3,4),
               x2=c(1,2,3),
               x3=c(5,76,7),
               x4=c(4,6,0))

make_matrix<-function(df){
  with(dat, matrix(c(x1,x2,x3, x4),byrow=T,nrow=2, ncol=2))
  }

apply(dat, 1, FUN=make_matrix)
  
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `asplit`

```
lapply(asplit(dat, 1), matrix, 2, 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    1
#[2,]    5    4

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    2
#[2,]   76    6

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    3
#[2,]    7    0
```

---

The OP's function argument and the body is not matching i.e. it takes an argument 'df' and inside the function uses `dat`.  But, that is not the only issue.  When we loop over the row, it is a vector of values and `with` will not work on those.  As we need a `list`, the `matrix` can be wrapped in a `list`

```
make_matrix <- function(x) list(matrix(x, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
```

should work

```
do.call(c, apply(dat, 1, make_matrix))
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    1
#[2,]    5    4

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    2
#[2,]   76    6

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    3
#[2,]    7    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `array`

```
mat <- array(c(t(dat)), c(2, 2, 3))
mat[] <- apply(mat, 3, t)
```

which gives

```
> mat
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    5    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    2
[2,]   76    6

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    3
[2,]    7    0
```

---

If you want to have result in the form of `list`, you can try

```
Map(t, asplit(array(c(t(dat)), c(2, 2, 3)), 3))
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    5    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    2
[2,]   76    6

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    3
[2,]    7    0
```